# Communicate with a serial device in a WPF application

Tags: wpf, mvvm, serial-port

I'm dabbling with the basics of communicating with a serial device from within a WPF application implementing an MVVM design.  Right now I have a hard loopback and only expect to receive characters sent.

I have in the past seen hints of a Win Forms control to do this, and maybe a framework class, but right now I am a bit clueless as to what I can use in the spirit of an MVVM strategy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a bit confused and it seems to me you might be overthinking MVVM. MVVM is a presentation pattern; serial communication is not presentation and it doesn't matter what your presentation layer is.

If I were to do this and I understand your problem correctly, I would have a class that encapsulates the serial communication. If you are only expecting characters to be sent to you, I'd have the class expose a basic "Received" event. Your View Model can then use an instance of this class to populate some properties that your View is attached to.

Hope this helps.

Comment: MVVM is not just about presentation (actually presentation and input), but displaying characters received by my model code is very much a presentation issue.  I know what you mean with the event though.

Comment: Input is part of presentation. In any case, a good design practice would be to wrap this serial communication and expose is to some consuming class. Whether the class is a view, a vm, a presenter, a controller... that is a separate issue. I guess I misunderstood your question.